# Limit of spectral projection of increasing sequence of positive operators

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Suppose $(x_\alpha)\subset \mathcal M$ is bounded increasing net of positive operators converging to a positive operator $x\in\mathcal M.$ Is it true that $\chi_{[0,1]}(x_\alpha)$ is an increasing net of positive operators converging to $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$?

Comment: I think this is isn't true even for a commutative Von Neumann algebra, where the spectral projections have a very concrete form.

Comment: If $x_1 = 1/2$ and $x_2 = 2$ then $\chi_{[0,1]}(x_i)$ is not increasing.

Comment: Another example to consider is $\mathcal{M} = L^\infty([0,1])$, $x_n(t) = (2 - \frac{1}{n})t$, $x(t)=2t$.  We have $x_n$ increasing to $x$ (in norm, i.e. uniformly on $[0,1]$), but $\chi_{[0,1]}(x_n)$ do not converge in norm.